# VUE(NUXT), upload button:, How it must not refresh when taking picture in IOS webview?

Tags: javascript, ios, vue.js, webview, nuxt.js

I have a Vue Project that will take photo from Gallery,.. the project is being also used in IOS and Android Webview,. the problem is on the IOS,.. when after taking a picture it will refresh the page. But photo library and other selection are working. Does anyone know how should be solve this?

this is the takephoto in IOS:
[image]

this is the code:

```
<div class="style_value text-left">
   <input ref="ImageFileHiddenInput" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" @change="onFileChange" type="file" name="image_file" style="display: none" />

   <button @click="$refs.ImageFileHiddenInput.click()" class="m-1" type="button" size="mini"><i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> Upload</button>

 </div>
```

```
 onFileChange(e) {
      const file = e.target.files[0];
      this.imageFile = file;
      this.uploadImage();
    },
    uploadImage() {
      if (this.imageFile) {
       
        var bodyFormData = new FormData();
        bodyFormData.append("UploadFile", this.imageFile);
       

        this.$axios
          .post(`/upload-photo-file-url`, bodyFormData)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log('success')
          })
          .catch((err) => {
           
            console.error(err);
          });
      }
    },
```

Comment: Please do not post code images but actual formatted text.

Comment: @kissu i Just protecting some codes,.. i will edit the question